# comparing lists of tokenized words to a set of words

Tags: python, nlp

I want to know if reviews are related to the subject or not, so I built a set of words that have a relation with subject.

```
effi_set = {"reminders","medication", "Alarm"
"diet", "carbohydrate","nutrition","weight","IBM", "sport", "activity", "fitbit","blood","insulin",
"Hb1ac" , "data exportation","feedback", "monitoring","recording ","monitor", "record",
"passwords","security","backup","protection",
"information","education","complication","risk","prevent","contact","consultation",
"facebook","twitter","social media","mail","FAQ","doctor",
"data","offline","language","location","region","country",
"devise","glucometer","bluetooth","automation","carb","barcode","food","syncronize","PHR","import"}
```

I tokenize each review to compare the tokenized words to subj_set

```
for line in df["content"]:
    tokenized_words =word_tokenize(line)
    for item in tokenized_words:
        if item not in effi_set:
            df["efficient"] = False
        else:
            df["efficient"] = True
```

the result was that all reviews all false which is not the case.

Comment: How would you know that `that all reviews all false` if you're just updating a boolean indicator with `df["efficient"] = False`?

Comment: df.head()
df.to_csv("Final_comments.csv", index=False)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df["efficient"] = False` is mofifing the whole column

You have to modify a row at a time

```
df["efficient"] = False
for index, line in df["content"].iteritems():
    tokenized_words =word_tokenize(line)
    for item in tokenized_words:
        if item in effi_set:
            df.at[index, "efficient"] = True
            continue
```

Comment: didn't work 
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Edited ! forgot the `index` in the loop

Comment: it works but the result is the same the efficient column is all  False

Comment: Ok. What is your code supposed to do ? should efficient be `True` if only one tokenized_words is found in `effi_set` ? Because here it keeps looping, so if the last element of `tokenized_words` is not found it will set `efficient` to false

Comment: yeah   efficient   True when at least one word of    tokenized_words   is found in effi_set  so once he found a word set efficient to True and execute the next list of tokenized_words